# owncloud cron execution within docker

Tags: php, mysql, cron, docker

Im using php-apache image to create an owncloud installation. I want to use a system cronjob to execute cron.php, therefore I run:

```
RUN echo "*/3 * * * * php -f /var/www/html/cron.php >> /oc_data/cron.log" > /cron.conf \
        && crontab -u www-data /cron.conf
```

The entrypoint script starts cron with:

```
cron -f
```

It gets executed but the owncloud.log shows following message:

```
"app":"cron","message":"Failed to connect to the database: An exception occured in driver: could not find driver"
```

Fun thing is, if I enter the docker container and execute the command I use for the cronjob, it works. And `php --ini` shows all php conf.d extensions including mysql.so and pdo_mysql.so.

I also tried to add the cron.conf file as user root with the same result.

Any ideas, what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, ALWAYS use absolute paths!!

path of the php command using the bash in the docker container was different to the one cron used.

use `which php` to get the correct path and add it to the cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the correct folder to keep your cron files: "/etc/cron.d/", use COPY to copy the cron file to inside container and "cron -f" in CMD parameter instead ENTRYPOINT.

Comment: It normally doesn't matter where I put the files and how I enable it. However I put the file into the cron.d folder and started cron -f with CMD, but it makes no difference. Still getting the same error message in the owncloud.log